# Firewalld - add IP to ipset dynamically from rich rule

Tags: centos, firewalld

Is there any option to add the source IP to an ipset dynamically from a rich-rule?
Basically, when there's a port hit, i need to add the source IP to an ipset.

Also, is there any option to add a timeout ? For example, add the IP to the ipset for 24 hours ?